# Create new data set based on a unique ID and frequency of same data in a row

Tags: r

I have data set DATA1(I am providing a trim version of data here) which has customer_id and there bookings(three different kind of bookings are denoted by 1,2,3.

I want to make a new table Output out of this table which will have Customer ID and frequency of Type1 booking which is denoted by 1 here.

```
Customer_ID Booking
1   1
2   2
2   1
2   2
3   2
3   1
3   2
3   3
3   1
4   2
4   3
```

Required Output is

```
Customer_ID Frequency_Type1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   0
```

Comment: `table(mydf$Customer_ID, mydf$Booking == 1)[, "TRUE"]`?

Comment: You might also just want `table(mydf)`, with which you can do things like `table(mydf)[, "1"]`, `table(mydf)[, "2"]`, and so on to get tables for the different "Booking" kinds.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just looking at frequencies, you should just be able to use `table`.

Example:

```
table(mydf)
##            Booking
## Customer_ID 1 2 3
##           1 1 0 0
##           2 1 2 0
##           3 2 2 1
##           4 0 1 1
```

Then, if you wanted just the first column, you could do:

```
table(mydf)[, "1"]
## 1 2 3 4 
## 1 1 2 0
```

This would give you a named vector. If you wanted that as a `data.frame`, you could `stack` it and rename the columns if required:

```
stack(table(mydf)[, "1"])
##   values ind
## 1      1   1
## 2      1   2
## 3      2   3
## 4      0   4
```

Alternatively, you could be more verbose and use `with(mydf, table(Customer_ID, Booking == 1)[, "TRUE"])`.

Comment: Alternately, `tab = data.frame(table(DT)); subset(tab, Booking == 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `xtabs` to calculate the frequency

```
xtabs(Booking~Customer_ID, df[df$Booking ==1, ])

#Customer_ID
#1 2 3 4 
#1 1 2 0
```

Another base R solution would be converting the `Customer_ID` into `factor` and then use `table` on only those rows where `Booking` is equal to 1.

```
df$Customer_ID <- as.factor(df$Customer_ID)
table(df[df$Booking ==1, ])

#          Booking
#Customer_ID 1
#          1 1
#          2 1
#          3 2
#          4 0
```